# Is it warranted to allow OPs to override edits without review?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Yesterday I made an edit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046457/no-project-option-in-visual-studio-code), which removed extraneous tags from the post. Apparently, at least one reviewer agreed with me, as the change was merged.

However, the OP [rolled back the change](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46046457/3), seemingly without going through the review process on SO.

[image: Post Revision section]

Regardless of whether or not the rollback was warranted, I do not think the rollback should have been allowed to be accepted without going through the suggested edit review queue. Am I wrong?

Comment: yeah, the OP should be able to edit their question without review. They are the most applicable person to be submitting edits, they're the one with a problem to solve. If they vandalize, or start an edit war, a moderator flag would be the next step.

Comment: @KevinB Agreed. They should always be able to edit their post. What I am asking is whether or not the rollback was okay.

Comment: I don't see a rollback as being much different from an edit.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know if you should spend time editing this kind of question...

Comment: Not only futile, but actually counter productive. Your edit occupies space in the approval queue, and time is spent evaluating a question that very likely should be closed as off-topic and deleted.

Comment: Would it really be any different if they had just edited the tags back into the question instead of rolling the edit back? Either way the results are the same but one method is less error prone.

Comment: Yeah, those are very valid arguments.

Comment: This has been the case for as long as edits have existed. The original poster has the ability to roll back or make any edit to their post without review. I'm guessing the reason this caught your eye now was because of [the relatively recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/135615) that causes your edit to be marked as rejected when this happens. An OP has always been able to edit their post without review, and has always been able to single-handedly approve edits to their posts. The edit rejection after the fact is what's new, and that might be what you have a problem with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it warranted to allow OPs to override edits without review?

Yes. They always have been able to do this. The OP can edit their post at any time without approval from anyone. Even if they would not have been able to retroactively reject your suggested edit, they could have simply rolled it back. Or just made a brand new edit of their own.

As [Brad Larson said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356162/is-it-warranted-to-allow-ops-to-override-edits-without-review/356182#comment511186_356162) the only thing new here is that we now allow the OP (and moderators) to *retroactively* change the dispensation of a suggested edit (so, approve one that was rejected by reviewers, or reject one that was approved by reviewers). That's what happened here, and it's probably why you noticed it—because you lost the +2 reputation gain from having your edit approved. On balance, this change is a good one, and an isolated case of a good edit being erroneously rejected is not sufficient reason to call the feature into question.

> I do not think the rollback should have been allowed to be accepted without going through the suggested edit review queue. Am I wrong?

Yes, you are wrong. We don't want to have to review every edit made by an OP. That would just be madness. If they want to add additional information or make changes, then they should be able to do so unimpeded, just like an editor with full editing privileges.

If something goes wrong in that process (like a rollback war between two editors), then you should use comments to inform/educate and/or raise a moderator flag to let one of us know.

I know you said

> Regardless of whether or not the rollback was warranted...

but I couldn't help myself here. The rollback was *not* warranted; your edit was good (although didn't quite go far enough), so I reinstated it. I can't override the override, of course, so you still don't get the +2 points for the suggested edit (sorry), but the question is now fixed, and that's what matters.

To be clear about why—the question is *about* Visual Studio Code, so none of the other tags regarding other versions of Visual Studio are relevant. The fact that the asker is mentally comparing to behavior to other versions of Visual Studio is not enough to warrant the tag.

More generally, version-specific tags should only be used when your question concerns that particular version. Using more than one version-specific tag is an "anti-pattern" that you were right to recognize and reject.

Comment: I think moderators should always be able to have the last say on a review. I think it's insane that we allow clueless or malicious askers to get away with misusing asker-specific features (cf. accept locks).

Comment: As a moderator, I do not *want* the power to change "accepted" answer status. With that power comes too much responsibility. *Maybe* I could get behind giving moderators powers to unilaterally *remove* "accepted" status, effectively leaving no answer accepted and thus community voting controlling the sort order, but I don't want us to be the arbiters of correctness.

Comment: Yeah, at least for accepts a much better solution is to just prevent acceptance from holding an answer hostage, as has been proposed in the past.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it warranted to allow OPs to override edits without review?

Actually, you are already reviewing OP edit. Each time someone edits a question the system "bumps" the post so people can review it. Yeah, there's no queue for that, but it's review nonetheless.

Now, when you should feel compelled to do an action contrary to OP actions? When it makes the post objectively worse.

BTW, it could be OP confusion since [the UI can leave so much to wish for.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298526/213575)